Upgrade from Kubernetes 1.24 to 1.25 after repo deprecation
Hi as the title says I'm trying to upgrade to kubernetes cluster from 1.24 to 1.25
I've update the yum repo as stated by the kubernetes guide to this but I cant seem to get any kubeadm versions available.
Already changed the yum repo to this as stated by kubernetes site
[kubernetes]
name=Kubernetes
baseurl=https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.25/rpm/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.25/rpm/repodata/repomd.xml.key
exclude=kubelet kubeadm kubectl cri-tools kubernetes-cni

